# PostSharp - break other aspects

Tags: .net, dependencies, postsharp, aspects, conflict

I have two method that execute first the "Cache" aspect and next the "Log" aspect.
I want that, if I have a "cache hit" I don't have to Log anything! In other words, if a certain condition in "Cache" aspect is satisified then the "Log" aspect must be skipped.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is addressed here:

http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/2.0/Content.aspx/PostSharp.chm/html/30402cd7-58ab-49ac-8f5c-65f510174daf.htm